# Best way to refresh a lower environment database with production but keep the QA permissions intact

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, postgresql-14

New PostgreSQL DBA here.  We have a database in our production environment in AWS PostgreSQL Aurora cluster and a QA database in a lower region that is essentially a copy of the production database.  Periodically, we are asked to refresh QA with a copy of the stage database.  QA has significantly different users and permissions than production.

What is the best way to completely replace the QA database with a copy of the production database without having to reset the QA permissions each time?  Since pg_dumpall is not available in AWS, is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sbs/chap-manageddatabases.postgresql-rds-postgresql-full-load-pd_dump.html

Answer (score -2):

Did you try no-role-password option like

pg_dumpall --no-role-passwords

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-dumpall.html

You mentioned QA database in a lower region. Are you saying production and QA environments located in different AWS regions?

Comment: unfortunately, pg_dumpall is not available in AWS Postgresql

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).